# DropDownListFor - why selected element is always the first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a `DropDownListFor` in my View:

```
@model UserProfileViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PreferredLangID,
    new SelectList(Model.PreferredLanguages,
        "LanguageID",
        "DisplayName",
        Model.PreferredLang))
```

Controller action:

```
 public ActionResult EditProfile()
 {
     List<Language> languages = Code.LanguageLogic.GetAllLanguages();
     UserProfile profile = Code.ProfileLogic.GetUserProfile();
     var viewModel = new UserProfileViewModel
     {
         UserID = profile.UserID,
         PreferredLanguages = languages,
         PreferredLang = profile.PreferredLang
     };
     return View(viewModel);
 }
```

I thought, that if I gave `Model.PreferredLang` as 4th [paramater in `SelectList`'s contructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), that element will be selected in dropdown, when page loads. But selected element is always the first one in list.

The Model:

```
public class UserProfileViewModel
{
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    public Language PreferredLang { get; set; }
    public int PreferredLangID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Language> PreferredLanguages { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Is `profile.PreferredLang` a `Language` or a string represents `Language.LanguageID`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the details of the type, so I can't say for sure, but I'm guessing you might need:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PreferredLangID,
    new SelectList(Model.PreferredLanguages,
        "LanguageID",
        "DisplayName",
        Model.PreferredLang.PreferredLangId))
```

ETA:

Or, with your addition:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PreferredLangID,
    new SelectList(Model.PreferredLanguages,
        "LanguageID",
        "DisplayName",
        Model.PreferredLangId))
```

Answer (score 0):

The second snipped for View was correct:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PreferredLangID,
new SelectList(Model.PreferredLanguages,
    "LanguageID",
    "DisplayName",
    Model.PreferredLangId))
```

But the Controller was also missing something. `Model.PreferredLangID` must be also set:

```
var viewModel = new UserProfileViewModel
{
    UserID = profile.UserID,
    IsAdministrator = profile.IsAdministrator,
    PreferredLanguages = languages,
    PreferredLangID = profile.PreferredLang.LanguageID
};
```

I'm not sure, why this didn't work with

```
new SelectList(Model.PreferredLanguages,
    "LanguageID",
    "DisplayName",
    Model.PreferredLang.LanguageID))
```

Comment: In your case `Model.PreferredLang` is not set at all in your viewmodel.